# How can I enable AAD SSO for bot so we can get user information via Teams toolkit

Tags: botframework, teams-toolkit

I use Teams toolkit to develop bot.
How can I enable AAD SSO for bot so we can get user information like user token or email in our bot process.

I have tried the method described in this link, but I don't understand why it requires both AAD_APP_CLIENT_ID and BOT_ID simultaneously. Does this mean I need to register two sets of AAD applications? It seems to make management a bit complicated.

[https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/wiki/Develop-single-sign-on-experience-in-Teams](https://stackoverflow.com)

```
"webApplicationInfo": {
  "id": "${{AAD_APP_CLIENT_ID}}",
  "resource": "api://botid-${{BOT_ID}}"
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is the useless (and inappropriate) posting of the tags and nothing else. The title should be clear and descriptive enough that a future site user who is skimming a list of search results will know what it's about. For suggestions on writing a good title, see [ask]. Also, you'll find your experiences at SO will be much better if you take the time to complete the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Answer (score 0):

Teams Toolkit uses two AAD applications for Bot SSO.

One AAD is created by "aadApp/create" action for authentication, which is the AAD application in the "Configure app with Microsoft Entra ID" step in this [wiki](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/bot-sso-overview#enable-sso-for-a-teams-app).

The other is the AAD app used to create Azure Bot Service. You can check this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/abs-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=multitenant) for detail.